# Is it possible to have multiple bots on a single kik account?

Tags: kik

I have one bot already on my Kik account, but can't see a way to add more bots to the same account.
Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to create additional bots!  It's not possible to do it via the admin pages., you just have to ask Botsworth!